# Progress Dialog in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

How can I make a modal `JDialog` without buttons appear for the duration it takes a `Runnable` instance to complete and have that instance update a progress bar/message on that dialog?

Clearly spaghetti code might work, but I'm looking for a clean design if one exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to look into [ProgressMonitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html). It automatically pops up a dialog with a progress bar if the operation is taking a long time; see [How to Use Progress Monitors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

Comment: Except for the cancel button? :P

Comment: Yes, it's not ideal, but it does answer the question exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the project described at the following URL:
http://digilander.libero.it/carlmila/compmon/main.html

It is a free Java library alternative to the Swing ProgressMonitor.

Answer (score 1):

Use a monitor class whit a global instance and which your code keeps up to date (I'm starting, I'm working, I'm at xxx%, I'm done).

The monitor can then decide to show the dialog and keep it current. Later, you can simply replace the dialog with a progress bar in the status bar, for example. Use an interface for the monitor (methods: start(), update(), end(), error(), isAborted()) so you can replace it with something else, too.

You can extend the monitor to wait for 500ms after start() if there is an end() and not show the dialog in this case, etc.

This is how [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) does it and it works well.