# How do you update a JDialog with new information?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jdialog

I have a Gui which allows the user to click a button and view the contents of a text file. The issue is that the file can be rather large (100,000+ rows of data) and can take upwards of 15 seconds to read and display in a table.

An example of the format of the text file:

```
*/
    Account ID     : 8 digit number
    Money Charged  : Integer < $10
    Values separated by \t 

/*


Account Id    Money Charged
----------    --------------
731298        3
359412        5
624937        1
```

So when the button is clicked, it reads each line and puts each id into a map and increases the charges of the accounts.

Once it is finished it will place a JTable inside a JDialog with the information. However, as soon as the button is clicked, the user could be confused as to what the program is doing as I've experienced upwards of 10-15 seconds of delay before the JDialog & JTable appears.

So is there a way to make the JDialog appear with a string letting the user know that it is creating the table? (I thought it would be done using one of the JDialog methods such as `repaint()` or `validate` but those didn't seem to do the trick.

Here is the order I'm thinking it should be done:

```
//Psuedo-code
actionPerformed {
    create frame
    display label that lets user know its creating table
    read text file
    create map and place values
    remove label
    update dialog with table // unsure what to do to update it properly
}
```

***So my overall question is simple:***
Is it possible to inform the user that it is currently calculating the data (via JLabel in the JDialog) and once the data is read, display the JTable (by updating the JDialog)?

If needed, I can provide source. Not sure it's really needed though

***Edit***

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Account Charges", true);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Currently calculating the charges")

    dialog.getContentPane().add(label);       //add waiting label
    dialog.setVisible(true);              
    readData(myFile);                         //read file and create table
    dialog.getContentPane().remove(label);    //waiting label no longer needed
    dialog.getContentPane().add(myJtable);    //update dialog with the table
}
```

Comment: `If needed, I can provide source. Not sure it's really needed though`, yes exactly, there are options like stars on the sky, which one is your, please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @mKorbel I assumed someone would ask for SSCCE which is why I added that last line. I still don't think it is needed to answer whether one is able to update a JDialog with new information. But I'll put together a simple program so there is an SSCCE

Comment: up to you, sure you cant do that, because question is very good described :-)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/511891/98811

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller I think a progress bar is a little too fancy for what I'm wanting to do. I'm just simply wanting to display a string/label. Reason being, sometimes it takes 100ms rather than 15+ seconds to create and load the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `I have a Gui which allows the user to click a button and view the contents of a text file.`

- use CardLayout, I'd to suggest to create another Container if you really needed to block or provide input mask for input / amend / delete of value that is already displayed or exist

2) `The issue is that the file can be rather large (100,000+ rows of data) and can take upwards of 15 seconds to read and display in a table.`

- I don't know any man except the internal revision, that could be want to check or working with 100k rows, use SwingWorker fills FileIO to the TableModel, and create paginations for JTable

3) //Psuedo-code

actionPerformed {

`create frame` - not JFrame re_use existing `JDialog`, sure better could be `CardLayout`

`display label that lets user know its creating table` - no idea let it be

`read text file` - use SwingWorker with JProgressBar, to transform data and put that to the TableModel, use batch for update of TableModel f.e. every 50rows, look for paginations for JTable, then you'll display only required numbers of rows, not 100k, this could be crazy :-)

`create map and place values` - could be useless because you are storing all required informations in the TableModel

`remove label` - no idea let it be

`update dialog with table` - Jtable could be updated immediatelly from SwinWorker, Swing GUI could be accesible for all Mouse or KeyBoards inputs, never waiting, nor delay at 10-15sec

}

Comment: I see why you wanted an SSCCE now. I think we misunderstood each other. The important part of what I was wanting to know was how to add/remove the label when the table was populated and then adding the table to the dialog rather than having the waiting label there. (I was in the process of creating the SSCCE when you posted your answer)

Comment: @WilliamShatner mKorbel is correct however. You should not block the UI for 15 seconds by creating your model on the EDT. The suggestion of a `SwingWorker` is very valid. I am not even sure you can guarantee your `JDialog` with the label will always be painted if you immediately start decoding your model on the EDT after you turned the dialog visible. And if you want to switch to something more dynamic then a label (say a progress bar or rotating icon) you need to free the EDT for a repaint. So `SwingWorker` is the way to go

Comment: @Robin I didn't mean to imply that mKorbel was incorrect in the least bit. I simply wanted to state that my question was only asking about updating the information displayed on the JDialog. (the user can close it whenever if they feel its taking too long). mKorbel answered quite a few things that I will definitely look into and learn about. Thanks for the advice from both you and mKorbel. I'm still learning and continuously looking to learn from those who have already conquered simple coding issues like the ones I encounter daily

Comment: @WilliamShatner I do not think the user can close it while you are decoding your model. That what I was trying to say ... you are blocking the EDT, hence your whole UI is unresponsive. That is the reason you should perform such tasks on a worker thread, and the `SwingWorker` class is designed for this

Comment: *"I was in the process of creating the SSCCE.."*  Have you solved the problem yet?  I only asked because you said that 11 hours ago, & there is an edit to your question about the same time adding some code snippets, yet this question still has no SSCCE.

Comment: After reading up on `SwingWorker` I believe you two are correct. I'll have to do this in a thread to make sure it updates without any issues. Thanks for the advice you two! @AndrewThompson, I deleted it when I read more into what Robin was saying. I was going about it wrong, I believe a thread is needed after viewing a few more examples

Comment: @WilliamShatner  Cool.  Hope it goes well for you. :)  If you have any problems implementing it, get back to us with a new question.

Answer (score 4):

`JDialogs` are able to hold components inside of them, such as the table you are talking about. You can simply tell the user what you are doing by using `JDialog's getContentPane` method to add/delete components such as a progress bar and label, so that they are notified that the program is working.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but `repaint()` is usually a method used by `java.awt` packages, and not so much `javax.swing` ... only on certain occasions.

-- Another Solution --
You could tell the user what's happening before the dialog even opens up. Maybe have a 'Current Status' label on the GUI or a progress bar. When the file is completely read and is ready to be used, you can open the dialog then and quickly post the values on the table.

Comment: I added an edit to show what I tried using the `getContentPane()` method, but it only shows the label? Do I need to set the dialog visible again once the table it created?

Comment: Also, you may be correct about `repaint()` I was just looking around at the methods of what might be possibilities to make it work. I also like your alternative solution and will keep it in mind in case I have to take it to that extent

Comment: `getContentPane().validate()` should do the job. It always helps looking at the Java API. Because `getContentPane()` returns a `Container`, I looked at the API for that particular class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html)

Comment: After trying a few times with this, I couldn't get it to automatically update. I think I may have to end up doing it in a thread as suggested by mKorbel and Robin

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to use your solution is to do `label.setVisible(false)` when your operation is complete. Of course your lay-outmanagers (or otherwise a good free design) should be made so that the other components resize/reposition properly when the label becomes invisible. Normally it should happen automatically.

There will be other ways to do it, but you'll spend more time making them.

Comment: My issue is that it doesn't add the JTable when it is ready. I added some code to the bottom of my question as an example of what I'm doing

Comment: @WilliamShatner Oh yeah sorry, I've been making a java GUI application with the netbeans gui builder for 2 weeks now and I forgot there are other things than that for gui -_-