# MessageDialog that user can't close

Tags: java, swing

I want to show a Message Dialog to the user informing him that my application is busy and that he has to wait.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, 
        "Operation in progress", 
        "Waiting", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

I create this simple message dialog but user can easy close this window. This message dialog must close only from my code.

Comment: You might consider a progress monitor as per this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511857/progress-dialog-in-swing

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` to display the predefined dialog create a new [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) object yourself and prevent user closing with [`setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)).

Comment: You could also call `setUndecorated(true)` on the dialog to prevent it from being closed, which would remove the X button altogether.